# mui v5 styled Dialog not accepting styled width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have mui v5 dialog that I am not able to set its width using style() component.

```
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  Paper,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Close } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";

import React from "react";

const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)(({ theme }) => ({
  fullWidth: true, // it's not taking effect
  maxWidth: "lg",  // it's not taking effect
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  position: "absolute",
  top: theme.spacing(5),
  "& MuiDialog-paper": {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    position: "absolute",
    top: theme.spacing(5),
  },
  "& .MuiTypography-h6": {
    paddingRight: "0px",
  },
}));

export default function Popup(props) {
  const { title, children, openPopup, setOpenPopup } = props;
  return (
    <StyledDialog open={openPopup} onClose={() => setOpenPopup(false)}>
      <DialogTitle>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <ActionButton
            color="secondary"
            onClick={() => setOpenPopup(false)}
          >
            <Close />
          </ActionButton>
        </div>
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>{children}</DialogContent>
    </StyledDialog>
```

However, if I listed the props directly inside the  it works.

```
<StyledDialog fullWidth="true" maxWidth="lg">

</StyledDialog>
```

What is the correct way of setting up the width and maxWidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the styledDialog declaration:

```
const StyledDialog = styled((props) => (
    <Dialog
        fullWidth={true}
        maxWidth={'lg'}
        {...props}
    />
))(({ theme }) => ({
    // Your code to style the dialog goes here
}));
```

The problem on your code is that you arent passing the properties fullWidth and maxWidth to the component.

Comment: it works, but for validation. can you pass props next to the theme instead of styled(props)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `maxWidth: lg` and `fullWidth: true` like css, but they are only for the [Dialog API](https://mui.com/api/dialog/#props).

So you could use `maxWidth` in the component as an API like

```
<Dialog maxWidth="lg" fullWidth ... >
```

or you can add it as css style using theme.

```
const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)(({ theme }) => ({
  maxWidth: theme.breakpoints.values.lg, // there's no styling such fullWidth
  ...
}));
```

You could have a look at the [default theme](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/#explore).

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: @Moe, What is not working? Could it be more specific?

Comment: based on the documentation you need the fullwidth to work, how big it gets depends on maxWidth. go to fullwidth but max is the maxWidth. implementing it your way doesn't change the window size. it doesn't expand or anything.

Comment: You could inspect the browser how it actually works. Otherwise, please provide me with your sandbox or git repo so I could look into it.